# Read multiple different objects in a text file - Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a school project which consist in creating race-tournaments

I'm having an issue right now because I have multiple races-type (CarRace/BikeRace) which have Race as a parent
I'm saving an array of races no matter the specific type.

And now I need to load this list of races

```
public static ArrayList<Course> loadLRace(String name) {
    File inFile = new File(name+".txt");
    FileInputStream inFileStream;
    ArrayList<Race> lRace = new ArrayList<Race>();
    try {
        inFileStream = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        ObjectInputStream inObjectStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFileStream);

        int length = inObjectStream.readInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Race race = (Race)inObjectStream.readObject();
            lRace.add(Race);
        }
        inObjectStream.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lRace;
}
```

And I'm having a "non valid constructor" error, I guess this is because I don't deal with CarRace AND BikeRace separately, but how can I ?

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) + you haven't posted the definition of `Race`/`CarRace`/...

Comment: A non valid constructor error _could_ be caused by a number of things, but I would expect it to happen with a method looking something like a constructor.  But I don't see that in your question, just another single non constructor method.  Maybe you should update your question with code surrounding the actual problem.

Comment: this looks wrong to me:  Race race = (Race)inObjectStream.readObject();

the FileInputStream object will just return the content of the file, which is a string representation of your object.  you need to extract the info from that string and properly create your race objects: Race r = new Race(input1, inpput2, input3, etc);